# Questions on using raw sockets for sniffing UDP packets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, packet-sniffers

I want to use raw sockets for packet analysis/sniffing limited to UDP. Yes I am aware of wireshark and libpcap. The scope of my analyzer is very limited and has to be implemented in C on Linux.

I know that we start with:

```
            sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
```

Then while reading, using *recvfrom*, we use the flag MSG_PEEK.

Questions:

1. Is the MSG_PEEK flag required if we use SOCK_RAW? .
2. If I read from this socket, will I get all incoming UDP packets on all interfaces and ports?
3. Does the read (with MSG_PEEK flag or otherwise) allow reading non-blocking sockets just like it would be had MSG_PEEK flag not been used? (I am using epoll). In epoll_ctl, one has to specify the fd to be monitored. Are all UDP sockets mapped to this single socket? So, if data is available on any UDP socket opened by other processes, this socket's EPOLLIN event will be triggered?
4. Will this  reading (with MSG_PEEK or without) impact the reading of sockets in the actual program that use the packets for real applications?

Comment: If you're 'aware of wireshark and libpcap' why aren't you using them?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne They are too heavy for the limited stuff I want. Besides, I want to do  custom analysis and statistics that they do not offer out-of-the box.  I just want to get my basics right... I saw code that does sniffing without MSG_PEEK so was not sure... Even if I was using wireshark or libpcap, I would have liked to get answers to the above questions!!